# load and ready use together jquery

Tags: jquery

I have simple jquery functions hide and show. I want to call these functions from both `ready()` and `load()`events.

This is `ready()` condition, I want to use window `load()` as well for some reason.
Is there any way so that I can use both conditions together?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("body").on("change","[data-type=Type]",function(){
                    var E = $(this);
                    if(E.val() == "F"){
                        $("[data-type=Rating]").removeAttr("required");
                        $("[data-type=Rating]").parents(".parsley-row").first().parent().hide();
                    }else{
                        $("[data-type=Rating]").parents(".parsley-row").first().parent().show();
                    }
                });
                $("[data-type=Type]").change();
            });
```

Comment: You either need `document.ready` or `window.load`, but rarely both. Why do you believe you need this? Also note that running this under `window.load` most likely wouldn't work anyway, as the DOM isn't guaranteed to be ready so the attribute selectors wouldn't find anything.

Comment: actually i'm loading it inside popup and also in separate page. Inside popup its work with ready condition when i use window.load its not work. Inside separate page in which real time classes are appending with div so its hide div before appending class thats why i need window.load

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense, `window.load` is not relevant to that problem. Given that `load` fires *before* `ready`, if `ready` isn't working then `load` definitely won't either. It would help to have a working example of the code to diagnose what the actual problem is.

Comment: If you must go down this XY Problem route, then simply move your code to a new function and call it from doc.ready and window.load.  `$(document).ready(myStartup);$(window).load(myStartup);function myStartup() { $("body").on("change"...`  This will, as requested, run from *both* events.  You probably want a global `var init = false;` first then at the top of `myStartup` : `if (init) return; init = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promises to wait for one or many asynchronous events to be finished. Here is an example with jQuery for how you can wait for both your events, even though there is no guarantee that both of these events will be triggered.

```
var loadPromise = $.Deferred();
var readyPromise = $.Deferred();

$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('Document ready is triggered');
    readyPromise.resolve();

});

$(window).on('load', function(){

    console.log('Window load is triggered');
    loadPromise.resolve();

});

$.when(loadPromise, readyPromise).done(function(){

    console.log('Both window load and document ready are done');

});
```